# Cannot get the iteams from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

So, I have a problem with Redux. I cannot figure out why `todos` in my Redux store every time equal to `undefined` when I try to invoke it by console.log in `AddTodos` component (see the 3th container of code)? Even when I manually add the `todos` in redux store. What is I'm missing?

Also I want to admit, that in the `this.props.store.getState()` invoke of `todos` state displays and updates normally.

/* ACTION  */

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../Variables/Variables'

function AddTodo(text) {
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO,
        text
    }
};

export default AddTodo
```

/* REDUCER */

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../Variables/Variables'

const initialState = {
    todos: []
}

function TodoApp(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return initialState;
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            todos: [
                ...state.todos, 
                {
                    text: action.text
                }
            ]
        });
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export default TodoApp;
```

/* COMPONENT */

```
import React from 'react';
import addTodos from '../../Modules/addTodos'

class AddTodos extends React.Component{   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let input = document.querySelector('input');
        addTodos(this.props.store, input.value);

        console.log('New state ', this.props.store.todos, this.props.store.getState()); 
                          // this.props.store.todos 
                          //- even got an undefined
        input.value = '';    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form id="tp" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" />
                <button type="submit">Add todos</button>
            </form>
        );  
    }
}

export default AddTodos;
```

Comment: Did you connect the component to the store? For example: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#containersfilterlink.js

Comment: I mean, you need a container component wrapping your actual component to connect it with the store (passing the actions/state data to it)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't using redux's react bindings. Use them, passing redux down as props defies most of the benefit of redux.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux

Then you will create containers and they will receive state via a provider.